# How do I paint multiple objetcs that move at different speeds in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, graphics, jpanel

I am working on homework for class, and its late because I can't seem to understand the material despite all the research that I am doing. I am a beginner and do not know much in the way of java. Also, this is my first post so please be forgiving when you are reading this.

I am building on source code from my textbook, which I updated recently for past homework, but now I am trying to generate a class that draws multiple squares and moves those objects independently and at different speeds. They will all need to rebound off the walls as well. I followed the instructions and created two arrays that will hold the random x and y values between 1 and 10. However, I struggle with arrays and I am sure that I am not doing it correctly. So, I would love some feedback to see if I have it set up correctly.

I have a the jpanel pulling up and drawing, and as long as there is 1 square it is working fine bouncing off the walls, but things change when I draw more than one. The do not move independently and they also share the same speed. Some even disappear from time to time. This has really thrown me off. I appreciate any help!

In short, I am trying to paint new squares that all travel in different directions and at different speeds. Per the instructions we are suppose create and use a two arrays that handle the x and y values.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class DotsPanel extends JPanel
{
private int delay = 15;
private final int SIZE = 7, IMAGE_SIZE = 3;  // radius of each dot
private Timer timer;
private int x, y, i;
private ArrayList<Point> pointList;
static int [] xarray = new int [1000];
static int [] yarray = new int [1000];
Random rand = new Random();
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets up this panel to listen for mouse events.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public DotsPanel()
   {
      pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
      int [] xarray = new int [1000];
      int [] yarray = new int [1000];

      timer = new Timer(delay, new ReboundListener());
      addMouseListener (new DotsListener());
      addMouseMotionListener (new DotsListener());

      setBackground(Color.gray);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
      for(int i = 0; i < xarray.length; i++)
      {   
      xarray[i] = rand.nextInt(7);
      yarray[i] = rand.nextInt(7);
      }
      timer.start();          
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Draws all of the dots stored in the list.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
   {
      super.paintComponent(page);
      page.setColor(Color.BLUE); 

      for (Point spot : pointList)
      {  
        page.fillRect(spot.x-SIZE, spot.y-SIZE, 25, 25);
        page.drawString("Count: " + pointList.size(), 5, 15);
      }
   }



//*****************************************************************
   //  Represents the listener for mouse events.
   //*****************************************************************
   private class DotsListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
   {
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Adds the current point to the list of points and redraws
      //  the panel whenever the mouse button is pressed.
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
      {
            pointList.add(event.getPoint());    
            repaint();
      }
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
      {
        // initially I had two xarray and yarray in here just like in 
        // mouseClicked
        // but it did not change anything when removed  
      }
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Provide empty definitions for unused event methods.
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) 
      { 
          xarray[i] = rand.nextInt(7);
          yarray[i] = rand.nextInt(7);            
      }
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
   }
   private class ReboundListener implements ActionListener
   {
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Updates the position of the image and possibly the direction
      //  of movement whenever the timer fires an action event.
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {


            for (Point spot : pointList) 
            {   
                spot.x += xarray[i];
                spot.y += yarray[i];
                if (spot.x <= 0 || spot.x >= 700)
                    xarray[i] = xarray[i] * -1;
                if (spot.y <= 0 || spot.y >= 500)
                    yarray[i] = yarray[i] * -1;
                repaint();  
            }
      }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> However, I struggle with arrays and I am sure that I am not doing it correctly.

I wouldn't use Arrays.

Instead, have a `Ball` object manage its own state. Then you can have different color, speed, size etc for each `Ball`. Then when the `Timer` fires you just calculate the new position and repaint the `Ball`.

Here is an example to get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BallAnimation4
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        BallPanel panel = new BallPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BallAnimation4");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        //frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible( true );

        panel.addBalls(5);
        panel.startAnimation();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class BallPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

    public BallPanel()
    {
        setLayout( null );
        setBackground( Color.BLACK );
    }

    public void addBalls(int ballCount)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < ballCount; i++)
        {
            Ball ball = new Ball();
            ball.setRandomColor(true);
            ball.setLocation(random.nextInt(getWidth()), random.nextInt(getHeight()));
            ball.setMoveRate(32, 32, 1, 1, true);
//          ball.setMoveRate(16, 16, 1, 1, true);
            ball.setSize(32, 32);
            balls.add( ball );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (Ball ball: balls)
        {
            ball.draw(g);
        }
    }

    public void startAnimation()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(75, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        move();
        repaint();
    }

    private void move()
    {
        for (Ball ball : balls)
        {
            ball.move(this);
        }
    }


    class Ball
    {
        public Color color = Color.BLACK;

        public int x = 0;
        public int y = 0;
        public int width  = 1;
        public int height = 1;

        private int moveX = 1;
        private int moveY = 1;
        private int directionX = 1;
        private int directionY = 1;
        private int xScale = moveX;
        private int yScale = moveY;

        private boolean randomMove = false;
        private boolean randomColor = false;
        private Random myRand = null;

        public Ball()
        {
            myRand = new Random();
            setRandomColor(randomColor);
        }

        public void move(JPanel parent)
        {
            int iRight = parent.getSize().width;
            int iBottom = parent.getSize().height;

            x += 5 + (xScale * directionX);
            y += 5 + (yScale * directionY);

            if (x <= 0)
            {
                x = 0;
                directionX *= (-1);
                xScale = randomMove ? myRand.nextInt(moveX) : moveX;
                if (randomColor) setRandomColor(randomColor);
            }

            if (x >= iRight - width)
            {
                x = iRight - width;
                directionX *= (-1);
                xScale = randomMove ? myRand.nextInt(moveX) : moveX;
                if (randomColor) setRandomColor(randomColor);
            }

            if (y <= 0)
            {
                y = 0;
                directionY *= (-1);
                yScale = randomMove ? myRand.nextInt(moveY) : moveY;
                if (randomColor) setRandomColor(randomColor);
            }

            if (y >= iBottom - height)
            {
                y = iBottom - height;
                directionY *= (-1);
                yScale = randomMove ? myRand.nextInt(moveY) : moveY;
                if (randomColor) setRandomColor(randomColor);
            }
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
        }

        public void setColor(Color c)
        {
            color = c;
        }

        public void setLocation(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void setMoveRate(int xMove, int yMove, int xDir, int yDir, boolean randMove)
        {
            this.moveX = xMove;
            this.moveY = yMove;
            directionX  = xDir;
            directionY  = yDir;
            randomMove  = randMove;
        }

        public void setRandomColor(boolean randomColor)
        {
            this.randomColor = randomColor;

            switch (myRand.nextInt(3))
            {
                case 0:  color = Color.BLUE;
                         break;
                case 1:  color = Color.GREEN;
                         break;
                case 2:  color = Color.RED;
                         break;
                default: color = Color.BLACK;
                         break;
            }
        }

        public void setSize(int width, int height)
        {
            this.width  = width;
            this.height = height;
        }
    }
}
```

Since your Arrays only contain the Point you want to paint you don't have any information about the speed each point should be moved at. The best you could do is create a random amount each point should be moved each time its location is changed. This would give erratic movement as each time you move a point the distance would be random.

If you want more constant speed then you would need to create a second Array to contain the distance each point should move every time.

This starts to get messy creating a new Array every time you want a new property to be unique for the object you want to paint. That is why the approach to create a custom Object with multiple properties is easier to manage.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Your code is certainly more logical than what I am asked to do in the instructions. However, I am afraid that I may get further behind on the material if I don't go by the guidelines. As well as, not be ready for future projects that may involve the same material for this homework.

Should I just create two more arrays to deal with the speed for the x and y movements? Or, can I generate one array that handles that for the each square that is drawn? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Jfwhyte8, I can't answer your question because I don't understand your guidelines or what the example is trying to teach.

Comment: Thank you for your help and I am sorry I am just now getting back to responding to you. Life has been busy to say the least.
 
My objective is to add animation using a Timer so that the squares all move when drawn. I need to make each square move at random speeds (in x and y directions), and I need to have the squares "bounce" appropriately off all four sides of the screen. Additionally, my teacher said that we should use 2 arrays of size 1000 to hold random values between 1 and 10 for the X movements and Y movements. This should allow the rectangles to have independent movement speeds.

Comment: I got it fixed up. Turns out, it wasn't hard to use arrays. I was repopulating them when I didn't need to, and I needed a local variable to increment in the actionListener method. Thanks for your help!