# Swing threading vs timers in my program Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer

I'm looking for some guidance in finishing my program for my project. It is a simple simulation where multiple graphical objects are drawn at runtime and using a button to add another ball in this case to the jpanel, I had to rewrite my whole code to take in multiple objects at once just 2 days ago and last night I did some research when I got an exception...changed some code then got another exception in thread AWT EventQueue 0, after doing some more research many people suggested that dynamically drawing objects on a jpanel at runtime with a thread is a pain in the.... and I should just use a timer instead so this is where I am at right now. The Grid_Bag_Constraints can be ignored for the time being as its just to lay it out at the moment.
**My question is how could i make it so a new ball is added at runtime on the press of a button...sorry forgot to mention**

Ps yeh i tried playing round with validating the jpanels already :/

All guidance is appreciated :)

```
   Sim
=============
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Random;

        import javax.swing.*;


        public class Sim extends JPanel 

            private static final int UPDATE_RATE = 60; // Number of refresh per second



            public static int X = 640;
            public static int Y = 480;

            public static int numberOfBall = 3;

            public static boolean isRunning = true;


            public Sim() {
              // have some code here all commented out
            }



            public static void main(String[] args) {

                // Run GUI in the Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT) instead of main thread.

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // Set up main window (using Swing's Frame)
                        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simulation");
                        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
                        c.gridwidth = 3;
                        c.gridheight = 3;
                        balls balls = new balls();
                        frame.add(balls);
                        gui GUI = new gui();
                        frame.add(GUI);
                        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,720));
                        frame.setResizable(false);
                        //frame.setContentPane(new Sim());
                        frame.pack();
                        frame.setVisible(true);

                        new Thread(new bounceEngine(balls)).start();

                    }
                });
            }

            public static int random(int maxRange) {
                return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * maxRange));
             }





            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                invalidate();
                repaint();

            }



        gui
---------

        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


        public class gui extends JPanel {
            boolean shouldFill;
            public gui(){

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            if(shouldFill){
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                }

                AbstractButton addBallButton = new JButton("Add Ball");
                addBallButton.setMultiClickThreshhold(1500);

                addBallButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                        balls.listBalls.add(new Ball((new    Color(Sim.random(255),Sim.random(255), Sim.random(255))),20));
                        for(Ball ball : balls.listBalls){
                            System.out.print("I work ");
                        }
                        invalidate();
                        //repaint();
                    }
                });
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.weightx = 1;
                c.weighty = 0.5;
                add(addBallButton);




    bounceEngine
------------------
        import java.awt.*;
        import javax.swing.*;
        public class bounceEngine implements Runnable {

            private balls parent;
            private int UPDATE_RATE = 144;

            public bounceEngine(balls parent) {
                this.parent = parent;

            }


            public void run() {

                int width = Sim.X;
                int height = Sim.Y;

                // Randomize the starting position...
                for (Ball ball : getParent().getBalls()) {
                    int x = Sim.random(width);
                    int y = Sim.random(height);

                    int size = ball.getRadius();

                    if (x + size > width) {
                        x = width - size;
                    }
                    if (y + size > height) {
                        y = height - size;
                    }

                    ball.setLocation(new Point(x, y));


                }

                while (getParent().isVisible()) {

                    // Repaint the balls pen...
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {


                                getParent().repaint();

                        }
                    });

                    //I know this is dangerous to update it as the repaint method is called
                    for (Ball ball : getParent().getBalls()) {
                        move(ball);
                    }

                    try{
                       Thread.sleep(1000/UPDATE_RATE);
                    }catch (InterruptedException e){

                    }

                }
            }

            public balls getParent() {
                return parent;
            }

            public void move(Ball ball) {

                Point p = ball.getLocation();
                Point speed = ball.getSpeed();
                int size = ball.getRadius();

                int vx = speed.x;
                int vy = speed.y;

                int x = p.x;
                int y = p.y;

                if (x + vx < 0  || x + (size*2) + vx > getParent().getWidth()) {
                    vx *= -1;
                }
                if (y + vy < 0  || y + (size*2) + vy > getParent().getHeight()) {
                    vy *= -1;
                }
                x += vx;
                y += vy;

                ball.setSpeed(new Point(vx, vy));
                ball.setLocation(new Point(x, y));

            }

        balls(for all the balls)
---------------------------------

        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Random;
        import javax.swing.*;

        public class balls extends JPanel  {

            public static ArrayList<Ball> listBalls;

            public balls() {
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,480));
                setBackground(Color.white);
                listBalls = new ArrayList<Ball>(10);


                for(int i = 0; i < Sim.numberOfBall; i++){
                    listBalls.add(new Ball((new Color(Sim.random(255),Sim.random(255), Sim.random(255))),20));

                }

            }

            public ArrayList<Ball> getBall(){
                return listBalls;

            }


            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                for (Ball ball : listBalls) {
                    ball.paint(g2d);
                }
                g2d.dispose();
            }

            public ArrayList<Ball> getBalls(){
                return listBalls;
            }

        Ball(for 1 ball object blank class with basic constructor)
----------------------------------------------------------------------

        import java.awt.*;

        public class Ball {

            private Color color;
            private Point location;
            private int radius;
            private Point speed;


            public Ball(Color color, int radius) {

                setColor(color);

                speed = new Point(5 - Sim.random(20), 5 - Sim.random(20));
                this.radius = radius;

            }


            public int getRadius() {
                return radius;
            }

            public void setColor(Color color) {
                this.color = color;
            }

            public void setLocation(Point location) {
                this.location = location;
            }

            public Color getColor() {
                return color;
            }

            public Point getLocation() {
                return location;
            }

            public Point getSpeed() {
                return speed;
            }

            public void setSpeed(Point speed) {
                this.speed = speed;
            }



            protected void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {

                Point p = getLocation();
                if (p != null) {
                    g2d.setColor(getColor());
                    g2d.fillOval(p.x, p.y, radius*2, radius*2);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is but I did notice you are using invalidate() or repaint() in a painting method. Don't do this. A painting method is for painting only. You should invoke repaint() when you change a property of your class. For an example of painting multiple moving objects using a Timer you can check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358359/how-do-i-paint-multiple-objetcs-that-move-at-different-speeds-in-java/42358637#42358637

Comment: my bad I updated the post again with the question as well and thanks for that

Comment: "How would I add a new ball at runtime?" Well you appear to be doing that already, so what actual problem are you having?

Comment: the error i get when i press that button...Im trying to add multiple balls I know that I am adding one but already but thats as soon as the program starts, if the button is pressed I want it to add another ball but I get an error from the thread

Comment: The basic answer is, add a new ball to `listBalls`