# How to correctly perform multithreading so that icons on individual threads move across the screen together?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, animation, paintcomponent

I'm trying to create an animation in which a given number of icons start on the left side of the frame and move to the right side of the screen. The icons are lined up vertically and each is supposed to run on its own thread.

How do I get all icons to do this? I tried adjusting `posY` when I create each racer, but so far I can only get the last racer that's created to show.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Races {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel gui;
    private Icon img;
    private int imgWidth;
    private int imgHeight;
    private int numOfRacers;  // num of threads / racers

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Races(5);
    }

    public Races(int num) {
        numOfRacers = num;
        createGUI();
        frame.add(gui);
        frame.pack();  
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Off to the Races - by Brienna Herold");
        gui = new JPanel();
        gui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(imgWidth * 20, imgHeight * numOfRacers));

        img = new ImageIcon("races.png");
        imgWidth = img.getIconWidth();
        imgHeight = img.getIconHeight();

        int posY = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfRacers; i++) {
            System.out.println("Starting new thread..." + posY);
            racer = new Racer(posY);
            Thread racerThread = new Thread(racer);
            racerThread.start();
            posY += imgHeight;
        }
    }

    protected class Racer extends JPanel implements Runnable {
        private int lastPosX;
        private int posX;
        private int posY;

        public Racer(int _posY) {
            posX = 0;
            posY = _posY;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // Call the method on the JPanel
            super.paintComponent(g);
            img.paintIcon(gui, g, posX, posY);
            //posY += imgHeight;
            posX += lastPosX + 3;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gui.add(racer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You only ever add one Racer component to the frame.

> but so far I can only get the last racer that's created to show.

The "racer" variable points to the last Racer component created.

If you want multiple components then you will need to create a panel using a null layout. Then you need to add each Racer component to this panel and then add the panel to the frame. Using this approach you would move the component by using the setLocation(...) method of the component.

If you want to paint an image in a different location, then you would use a single panel which would contain an ArrayList or Racer objects. Then when the paintComponent() method of the panel is invoked you iterate through the List and paint each Racer at its new location.

Comment: Ooh. Let me try this.

Comment: Not you are not just painting. You can't paint a component unless you add a component to the frame.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. But look at your code. You have a loop that keeps creating new instances of your Racer component. Unless you add the component to the frame, the frame know nothing about the component so it can't possible paint it.

Comment: For an example of painting objects from an ArrayList check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358359/how-do-i-paint-multiple-objetcs-that-move-at-different-speeds-in-java/42358637#42358637

Comment: Yes, I had thought I understood `img.paintIcon(gui, g, posX, posY);` to mean that I would be painting the image onto the `gui` component at specified posX, posY, and that this would happen to each instance of Racer when it was created.