# repaint method inside run()

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt, paint

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Hunter extends JFrame implements KeyListener{


public class helper extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int randomm=(int)(Math.random()*4);
            int randommm = (int) ((Math.random() * 490) + 10);
            obj obj1 = new Hunter().new obj(randommm, 0);
            MyThreadTS k = new MyThreadTS(obj1, getGraphics());
            MyThreadS k1 = new MyThreadS(obj1, getGraphics());
            MyThreadM k2= new MyThreadM(obj1, getGraphics());
            MyThreadF k3 = new MyThreadF(obj1, getGraphics());
            MyThreadTF k4 = new MyThreadTF(obj1, getGraphics());

            switch (randomm) {
                case 0:
                    k.start();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    k1.start();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    k2.start();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    k3.start();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    k4.start();
            }
        }
    }

public class obj{
    int x,y;
    public obj(int x,int y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
}
public class MyThreadTS extends Thread{
    Graphics g;
    int x,y;
    public MyThreadTS(obj obj,Graphics g){
        this.x=obj.x;
        this.y=obj.y;
        this.g=g;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            while (y<491) {
                if ((x>=positionX && x<=positionX+50)&& 
               (y>=positionY && y<=positionY+50)
                ||(x+10>=positionX && x+10<=positionX+50)&& 
                (y+10>=positionY && y+10<=positionY+50)) {

                   stop();
                }

                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                y++;
                Thread.sleep(200);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
   }
public class MyThreadS extends Thread{
    Graphics g;
    int x,y;
    public MyThreadS(obj obj,Graphics g){
        this.x=obj.x;
        this.y=obj.y;
        this.g=g;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            while (y<491) {
                if ((x>=positionX && x<=positionX+50)&& 
                      (y>=positionY && y<=positionY+50)
                        ||(x+10>=positionX && 
                    x+10<=positionX+50)&&(y+10>=positionY && 
                  y+10<=positionY+50)) {

                    stop();
                }

                g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                y++;
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                Thread.sleep(100);

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public class MyThreadM extends Thread{
    Graphics g;
    int x,y;
    public MyThreadM(obj obj,Graphics g){
        this.x=obj.x;
        this.y=obj.y;
        this.g=g;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            while (y<491) {
                if ((x>=positionX && x<=positionX+50)&& 
     (y>=positionY && y<=positionY+50)
                        ||(x+10>=positionX && 
       x+10<=positionX+50)&&(y+10>=positionY && 
             y+10<=positionY+50)) {

                    stop();
                }

                Thread.sleep(50);
                y++;
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                //repaint();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}public class MyThreadF extends Thread{
    int x,y;
    Graphics g;
    public MyThreadF(obj obj,Graphics g){
        this.x=obj.x;
        this.y=obj.y;
    this.g=g;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            while (y<491) {
                if ((x>=positionX && x<=positionX+50)&& 
                (y>=positionY && y<=positionY+50)
                        ||(x+10>=positionX && 
                     x+10<=positionX+50)&&(y+10>=positionY && 
         y+10<=positionY+50)) {


                    stop();
                }

                Thread.sleep(25);
                y++;
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                //repaint();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}public class MyThreadTF extends Thread{
    int x,y;
    Graphics g;
    public MyThreadTF(obj obj,Graphics g){
       this.x=obj.x;
        this.y=obj.y;
        this.g=g;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            while (y <491) {
                if ((x>=positionX && x<=positionX+50)&& 
              (y>=positionY && y<=positionY+50)
                        ||(x+10>=positionX && 
               x+10<=positionX+50)&&(y+10>=positionY && 
         y+10<=positionY+50)) {

                    stop();

                }

                Thread.sleep(12);
                y++;
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                //repaint();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



public Hunter(){
    setSize(500, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    addKeyListener(this);
}
int positionX=250,positionY=250;
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(positionX,positionY,50,50);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
}


public static void main(String [] args){

    Hunter game=new Hunter();
    game.setVisible(true);
    Hunter.helper helper=game.new helper();
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    timer.schedule(helper,0, 300);
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
   int keyCode=keyEvent.getKeyCode();

   if (keyCode==38){
       if(positionY<10){

       }
       else {

           positionY -= 10;
           repaint();
       }
    }
    else if(keyCode==40){
        if (positionY>440){

        }
        else {
            positionY += 10;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    else if(keyCode==37){
        if (positionX<10){

        }
        else {
            positionX -= 10;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    else if(keyCode==39){
        if (positionX>440){

        }
        else {
            positionX += 10;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {}
     }
```

in my code i have a prey-hunter game.Blue square eat red and black rectangles.They are created randomly each 0.5 sec and they are falling down in a specific time.But i have a trouble with red and black rectangles because if i use repaint method for each new paint it doesn't work correctly.They looks cloudy.How can i fix this?

i want to create my red and black rectangles like that:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DPBL.png]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. This will increase your chance to get an appropriate answer. Furthermore it also helps you solving the question yourself. You will find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Great suggestion @Mathias, and a tip: `[mcve]` in a comment, automatically expands to [mcve].

Comment: Don't use getGraphics() for painting on a frame. Don't override paint() on a frame. Instead you should be doing custom painting on a JPanel by overriding the paintComponent() method. Then you keep an ArrayList of objects to paint. Then in the paintComponent() you iterate through the ArrayList to paint each object. Also, instead of having multiple threads you should invoke repaint() at a constant time interval. But each object can have a different velocity so it will appear to move faster/slower than other objects. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42358637/131872