# Why is only one ball being drawn? There should be many more

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to have an ArrayList of Ball objects, and I want to draw them to the screen, but only one of them gets drawn and I don't know why.

Ball class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ball extends JPanel{
    int sX,sY;
    Color color;
    int speed;
    int height;
    int width;
    int velX=0;
    int velY=0;
    Random randInt;
    JFrame window;
    public Ball(int sX,int sY,int height,int width){
        this.sX=sX;
        this.sY=sY;
        this.color=color;
        this.speed=speed;
        this.height=height;
        this.width=width;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setColor(color.RED);
        Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(sX,sY,width,height);
        g2d.fill(ellipse);

    }


    public String getCoords(){
        return "X: "+String.valueOf(sX)+" Y: "+String.valueOf(sY);
    }
}
```

BallManager class (where it stores the arraylist of ball objects)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BallManager {
    ArrayList<Ball> listOfBalls;
    int width,height;
    JFrame window;
    Ball newBall;
    public BallManager(JFrame window) {
        this.listOfBalls=new ArrayList<Ball>();
        this.window=window;
        this.addBalls(100);
        //this.drawBalls();
    }
    public void addBalls(int n){

        for (int y=0;y<n;y+=20){
            for(int x=0;x<n;x+=20){
                this.listOfBalls.add(new Ball(x,y,10,10));
                drawBalls();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(listOfBalls.size());

    }
    public void drawBalls(){

        for(Ball b:listOfBalls){
            window.add(b);
            System.out.println(b.getCoords());
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrameWindow j= new JFrameWindow(300,500);
        BallManager bm=new BallManager(j);
    }
}
```

Window Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JFrameWindow extends JFrame {
    int width;
    int height;
    public JFrameWindow(int width,int height){
        super("JFrame ballssssss");
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(this.width,this.height);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.orange);


    }


}
```

I have no clue what the problem is. It seems to me that the balls in the arraylist move in unison with each other but I don't know why.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358359/how-do-i-paint-multiple-objetcs-that-move-at-different-speeds-in-java/42358637#42358637 for a working example that paints multiple objects from an ArrayList.

Answer (score 3):

You've got some things a little backwards:

- The Ball class should *not* extend from JPanel nor any other Swing component. Instead it should be a *logical* class, one that knows the location, color of a ball and how to draw it, in a method, say `public void draw(Graphics g)`.
- There should be only one JPanel that holds the logical Balls in an `ArrayList<Ball>`, and draws them all within its `paintComponent` method via a for-loop.
- This single JPanel should be added to the JFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER.

e.g.,

```
public class Ball {
    private static final int RADIUS = 5;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Color color;

    // constructors

    // getters / setters

    // methods to move the ball

    // or might use Graphics2D and rendering hints to smooth drawing
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x - RADIUS, y - RADIUS, 2 * RADIUS, 2 * RADIUS);
    }
}
```

and

```
class BallPanel extends JPanel {
    private List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructor -- fill the balls list

    // other methods....

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Ball ball : balls) {
            ball.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to add my window class. Wonder if it makes a difference?

Comment: @JoshuaCarpenter-Jones: not really as your basic problem still exists -- trying to draw a single ball on a single JPanel and then creating multiple JPanels. And so my solution is the one correct one -- to make Ball a logical non-component class and draw in one and only one JPanel.

Comment: Thank you. I'll get on it now