# Adding shapes to a JPanel after a button is pressed

Tags: java

I cannot seem to find the answer to what I hope is a simple question. I am making a GUI in Java that lets the user select a shape from a list, enter in the required dimensions, and then when they press Draw, it draws the shape in the JPanel. However I have tried numerous different ways to get this to work but the shape never shows up.  Here is what I have so far.

After the user selects a shape then following code from UserInterface.java is run

```
case "Circle":
    choiceLabelText.setText("You have selected " + choice);
    Circle myCircle = new Circle(0,0,0);
    try {
        Double r = Double.parseDouble(Dim1_Box.getText());
        Double area = myCircle.getArea(r);
        AreaVolume.setText(String.valueOf(area));
        ShapePanel.add(new DrawCircle(ShapePanel.getWidth(), ShapePanel.getHeight()));
        ShapePanel.revalidate();
        ShapePanel.repaint();
        userInterface.pack();
        userInterface.repaint();                        
    } 
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        break;
    }
    break;
```

It calls on the DrawCircle class which is simply

```
public class DrawCircle extends JPanel {
    
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int w, h;
    
    public DrawCircle(int w, int h) {
        System.out.println("DrawCircle was called");
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
    }
    
}
```

And here is the full UserInterface.java file

```
public class UserInterface extends JFrame {
    
    JFrame userInterface;

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private java.awt.TextField AreaVolume;
    private javax.swing.JLabel ChooseShapeText;
    private java.awt.TextField Dim1_Box;
    private java.awt.Label Dim1_Label;
    private java.awt.TextField Dim2_Box;
    private java.awt.Label Dim2_Label;
    private java.awt.TextField Dim3_Box;
    private java.awt.Label Dim3_Label;
    private java.awt.TextField Dim4_Box;
    private java.awt.Label Dim4_Label;
    private java.awt.Button DrawButton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel ShapePanel;
    private java.awt.Label choiceLabelText;
    private java.awt.Label label1;
    private java.awt.Choice shapeSelection;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
    
    public UserInterface() {
        this.userInterface = new JFrame();
        initComponents(userInterface);
    }
    
    private JFrame getJFrame(){
        return this.userInterface;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents(JFrame userInterface) {

        ShapePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        shapeSelection = new java.awt.Choice();
        ChooseShapeText = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        choiceLabelText = new java.awt.Label();
        DrawButton = new java.awt.Button();
        Dim1_Box = new java.awt.TextField();
        Dim2_Box = new java.awt.TextField();
        Dim3_Box = new java.awt.TextField();
        Dim4_Box = new java.awt.TextField();
        Dim1_Label = new java.awt.Label();
        Dim2_Label = new java.awt.Label();
        Dim3_Label = new java.awt.Label();
        Dim4_Label = new java.awt.Label();
        AreaVolume = new java.awt.TextField();
        label1 = new java.awt.Label();

        userInterface.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        userInterface.setResizable(false);
       

/* vvv THE JPANEL I AM WORKING WITH */   ShapePanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout ShapePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(ShapePanel);
        ShapePanel.setLayout(ShapePanelLayout);
        ShapePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            ShapePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        ShapePanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            ShapePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 446, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
/* ^^^ THE JPANEL I AM WORKING WITH */   

        shapeSelection.add("--- Choose Shape ---");
        shapeSelection.add("Circle");
        shapeSelection.add("Square");
        shapeSelection.add("Triangle");
        shapeSelection.add("Rectangle");
        shapeSelection.add("Sphere");
        shapeSelection.add("Cube");
        shapeSelection.add("Cone");
        shapeSelection.add("Cylinder");
        shapeSelection.add("Torus");
        shapeSelection.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                shapeSelectionItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        ChooseShapeText.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        ChooseShapeText.setText("Choose Shape");

        DrawButton.setLabel("Draw!");
        DrawButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DrawButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Dim1_Label.setText("Radius");

        label1.setText("Area");

        GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(userInterface.getContentPane());
        userInterface.getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(ChooseShapeText)
                            .addComponent(choiceLabelText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 277, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(Dim2_Label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(Dim3_Label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(Dim4_Label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(Dim4_Box, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(Dim2_Box, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(Dim3_Box, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 196, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(Dim1_Label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(Dim1_Box, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(DrawButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(AreaVolume, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addComponent(shapeSelection, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(ShapePanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addComponent(ShapePanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(ChooseShapeText)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(shapeSelection, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(choiceLabelText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(Dim1_Box, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(133, 133, 133)
                                .addComponent(Dim1_Label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(Dim3_Box, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(Dim2_Label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(AreaVolume, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(202, 202, 202)
                        .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(Dim2_Box, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(Dim3_Label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                                .addComponent(Dim4_Box, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(Dim4_Label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                        .addComponent(DrawButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 62, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(55, 55, 55))
        );

        userInterface.pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
    
/* vvv THE METHOD CALLED WHEN THE USER MAKES A SELECTION */   
    private void shapeSelectionItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        String choice = shapeSelection.getSelectedItem();
        switch (choice) {
                case "Circle":
                    choiceLabelText.setText("You have selected " + choice);
                    Circle myCircle = new Circle(0,0,0);
                    try {
                        Double r = Double.parseDouble(Dim1_Box.getText());
                        Double area = myCircle.getArea(r);
                        AreaVolume.setText(String.valueOf(area));
                        int x = 25;
                        int y = 25;
                        //int radius = 5;
                        //Graphics2D circle = new Graphics2D();
                        //this.userInterface.getContentPane().add(label1)
                        //Graphics circle;
                        //int x = ShapePanel.getWidth()/2;
                        //int y = ShapePanel.getHeight()/2;
                        //int radius = 5;
                        //DrawCircle circle = new DrawCircle(1,1,1,1);
                        //ShapePanel.add(circle);
                        //ShapePanel.validate();
                        //ShapePanel.revalidate();
                        //ShapePanel.repaint();
                        //this.userInterface.revalidate();
                        //this.userInterface.repaint();
                        //ShapePanel.paintComponents(circle);
                        //circle.drawOval(x, y, radius, radius);
                        DrawCircle newJPanel = new DrawCircle(x, y, x, y);
                        newJPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
                        //ShapePanel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                                //int x = ShapePanel.getWidth()/2;
                                //int y = ShapePanel.getHeight()/2;
                                //ShapePanel.add(new DrawCircle(x, y, 50, 50));

                        javax.swing.GroupLayout ShapePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(newJPanel);
                        newJPanel.setLayout(ShapePanelLayout);
                        ShapePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                            ShapePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        );
                        ShapePanel = newJPanel;
                        
                        userInterface.revalidate();
                        userInterface.pack();
                        userInterface.repaint();
                        //userInterface.add(new DrawCircle(x, y, x, y));
                        
                    } 
                    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Square":
                    choiceLabelText.setText("You have selected " + choice);
                    //Square mySquare = new Square(2,0,0);
                    //mySquare.getArea();
                    myCircle = new Circle(0,0,0);
                    try {
                        Double r = Double.parseDouble(Dim1_Box.getText());
                        Double area = myCircle.getArea(r);
                        AreaVolume.setText(String.valueOf(area));
                    } 
                    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            } 
    }
/* ^^^ THE METHOD CALLED WHEN THE USER MAKES A SELECTION */  

    private void DrawButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_DrawButtonActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_DrawButtonActionPerformed
    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new UserInterface().getJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
    }
    
}
```

Any helpful pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: helped simplify the code by removing all of my testing stuff

Comment: You need to do your drawing in one and only one JPanel, but add shapes to it to be held in an ArrayList, and then in the JPanel's paintComopnent method, iterate through the array list, drawing each shape. Please see Camickr's answer in the duplicate, and please ask if questions.

Comment: Also a great answer in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678649/adding-shapes-to-jpanel-on-a-button-click)

Comment: So, change `public class DrawCircle extends JPanel {` so that it ***no longer extends JPanel***.  Remove its `@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {` method and instead give it a `public void draw(Graphics g)` method and ***call that method*** within the one single JPanel's drawing paintComponent method.

Comment: Please also see [my answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435716/why-is-only-one-ball-being-drawn-there-should-be-many-more) for more on this

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you for linking those two. I stepped away from this to eat and refresh my mind a little. I will read those and see if they can help solve my problem

Comment: I will also try the modifications you mentioned as well. Thank you for such a fast response. I will post again once I have an update.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I changed my DrawCircle class to now be `public class DrawCircle` and replaced my paintComponent method to be 

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
    }
```

However I am still confused on the answers you posted. According to your answers, I would need to make my UserInterface class extend JPanel instead of JFrame in order to add the following method

Comment: ```
@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        DrawCircle circle = new DrawCircle(ShapePanel.getWidth(), ShapePanel.getHeight());
        circle.draw(g);
    }
```

Comment: I just need the JPanel to display the circle, square, rectangle, etc only one time when the button is pressed so I am not sure how using a list and for loop would help. The user presses the button and any shape in the JPanel are removed and then replaced with the requested shape. More importantly, I am not sure how I would call this `paintComponent` method in the first place since my JPanel variable only has a `paintComponents` method that I can call? I might be missing something fundamental here sorry