# Array2d to GUI Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have an array2d of Object

```
Person[][] universo = new Person[x][y];
```

I have a method that allows This Object to move through the array2d 
Now... Is possible to rappresent this array and all the movements in a grapichs windows, like pixel?

like this photo:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU8by.jpg]

obviously every time I call the Move method, the pixels move and must change position even in the window

EDIT::::::
 I Use the code of Richard Bernard

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rffVT.png)

why all Object are drawn on the first box?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Did you try anything?

Comment: no man, I can program in java but I have never faced a graphic problem

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358359/how-do-i-paint-multiple-objetcs-that-move-at-different-speeds-in-java/42358637#42358637 for an example that shows animation of objects moving around the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a draw(Graphics g) method to the Person class which will use AWT graphics to draw a representation of the Person instance.

```
public void draw(Graphics g, int cellWidth, int cellHeight) {
  /*
  do your drawing here, look into
  AWT Graphics for examples on how
  to draw.
  */
}
```

Create a JFrame, add a JPanel, override the JPanel's paintComponent() method, Which draws a grid representing the 2d array, then have this method iterate over all Persons in your matrix and call each one's draw method.

```
    // essentially the "frame" around the 
    // new window you will draw the GUI inside of
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    int width = 400, height = 400;
    frame.setSize(width + 40, height + 60);

    int cellWidth = width / cols;
    int cellHeight = height / rows;

    // The panel, which is the surface you will draw on
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.translate(15, 10);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            // drawing universo
            // drawing vertical lines (column borders)
            for(int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
                int dx = (int)(i * width / (double)cols);
                g.drawLine(dx, 0, dx, height);
            }
            // drawing horizontal lines (row borders)
            for(int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
                int dy = (int)(i * height / (double)rows);
                g.drawLine(0, dy, width, dy);
            }
            // draw all your Person objects
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    // optionally pass cellWidth and cellHeight to help
                    // draw the Person object in the correct cell.
                    if(universo[i][j] != null) {
                        universo[i][j].draw(g, cellWidth, cellHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Place the panel inside of the frame
    frame.add(panel);

    // make the frame and its contents visible on the screen
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Now, depending on how frequently your Person objects have move() called on them, I would approach repainting the JPanel differently.

If it is very infrequent, you could have a moveAndRepaint(Person p) method which essentially calls p.move() and then repaint() on the JPanel instance in your JFrame.

```
public void moveAndRepaint(Person person, JPanel panel) {
    person.move();
    panel.repaint();
}
```

If it is very frequent, you could call move on all Person instances in your matrix, and then one call to repaint() on the JPanel.

```
public void moveAllAndRepaint(Person[][] universo, JPanel panel) {

    // call move on all Person objects in the universo
    for(int j = 0; j < universo.length; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < universo[j].length; i++) {
            if(universo[i][j] != null) {
                universo[i][j].move();
            }
        }
    }

    // redraws everything in the panel to reflect changes in the
    // Person objects
    panel.repaint();
}
```

Comment: `what should the draw method do?` - working example already provided.

Comment: The cell width and height are passed to the draw function so that you can multiply whatever coordinates your Person objects have by those to get their position in the drawn grid. For example, if your persons are limited to the range (0 to rows-1) then you simply multiply that Person object's x by cellWidth to get it's position in the grid. If this multiplication is not occurring, they may all draw into the first cell closer to the origin.

Comment: ok ok, work... now where can i call the method MoveAllandRepaint?

Comment: @EdwardLuciani, `now where can i call the method MoveAllandRepaint?` - you use a Swing Timer, which is also demonstrated in the working example.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible but i am not sure (i dont think its possible) to update the same window. Rather everytime you run a new window will open . To do this you  will need certain libraries such as Jung or JgraphT .

This is a Link to  even i did ,[a working Jung tutorial](http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/JUNG2-Tutorial.pdf)
This is a link to one i [JgraphT tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jgrapht)

Take a look at these, you will need to install few packages and libraries to work with these, also some Jar files needs to be added into the project libraries .It is a bit tricky but certainly do-able .[image: This is something i got using Jung.]
Good luck hope it works out for you too

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer addresses the problem, and the limitations you are suggesting are certainly not applicable to swing, as the original question is tagged with.