# How to create a LinkedList that adds a circle after every 10 seconds and removes the first element (circle) after every 15 seconds

Tags: java, swing, canvas

I am done with randomizing circles, now my challenge is on adding circles to a straight line queue like the actual queue(i want the circles to queue from left to right preferably at the top of the Frame. When i call the removeCircle(), i want the circle to leave the queue and move down the frame. Can you help me with the addCircle() and removeCircle() methods. Thank you in advance.

```
public class AirTrafficLanding
{
private static void createAndShowUI()
{
    PlanePanel panel = new PlanePanel(1);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Air traffic Landing System");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.add( panel );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible( true );

    panel.startAnimation();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            createAndShowUI();
        }
    });

}

static class PlanePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private ArrayList<Plane> planes = new ArrayList<Plane>();

    public PlanePanel(int planeCount)
    {
        Dimension screenSize =  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        setLayout( null );
        setBackground( Color.BLACK );

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < planeCount; i++)
        {
            Plane plane = new Plane();
            plane.setRandomColor(true);
            plane.setLocation(0, 700);
            //plane.setLocation(random.nextInt(screenSize.width), random.nextInt(screenSize.height));
            plane.setMoveRate(32, 32, 1, 1, true);
            plane.setSize(32, 32);
            planes.add( plane );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (Plane plane: planes)
        {
            plane.draw(g);
        }
    }

    public void startAnimation()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(55, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        move();
        repaint();
    }

    private void move()
    {
        for (Plane plane : planes)
        {
            plane.move(this);
        }
    }
}

static class Plane
{
    public Color color = Color.BLACK;

    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;
    public int width  = 1;
    public int height = 1;

    private int moveX = 1;
    private int moveY = 1;
    private int directionX = 1;
    private int directionY = 1;
    private int xScale = moveX;
    private int yScale = moveY;

    private boolean randomMove = false;
    private boolean randomColor = false;
    private Random myRand = null;

    public Plane()
    {
        myRand = new Random();
        setRandomColor(randomColor);
    }

    public void move(JPanel parent)
    {
        int iRight = parent.getSize().width;
        int iBottom = parent.getSize().height;

        x += 5 + (xScale * directionX);
        y += 5 + (yScale * directionY);

        if (x <= 0)
        {
            x = 0;
            directionX *= (-1);
            xScale = randomMove ? myRand.nextInt(moveX) : moveX;
            if (randomColor) setRandomColor(randomColor);
        }

        if (x >= iRight - width)
        {
            x = iRight - width;
            directionX *= (-1);
            xScale = randomMove ? myRand.nextInt(moveX) : moveX;
            if (randomColor) setRandomColor(randomColor);
        }

        if (y <= 0)
        {
            y = 0;
            directionY *= (-1);
            yScale = randomMove ? myRand.nextInt(moveY) : moveY;
            if (randomColor) setRandomColor(randomColor);
        }

        if (y >= iBottom - height)
        {
            y = iBottom - height;
            directionY *= (-1);
            yScale = randomMove ? myRand.nextInt(moveY) : moveY;
            if (randomColor) setRandomColor(randomColor);
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void setColor(Color c)
    {
        color = c;
    }

    public void setLocation(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setMoveRate(int xMove, int yMove, int xDir, int yDir, boolean randMove)
    {
        this.moveX = xMove;
        this.moveY = yMove;
        directionX  = xDir;
        directionY  = yDir;
        randomMove  = randMove;
    }

    public void setRandomColor(boolean randomColor)
    {
        this.randomColor = randomColor;

        switch (myRand.nextInt(3))
        {
            case 0:  color = Color.ORANGE;
                     break;
            case 1:  color = Color.GREEN;
                     break;
            case 2:  color = Color.RED;
                     break;
            default: color = Color.BLACK;
                     break;
        }
    }

    public void setSize(int width, int height)
    {
        this.width  = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

}

I am expecting to start with zero circles in a queue and add one circle at 10 seconds interval. I want one circle to move from the queue to the bottom of the queue after every 15 seconds. I am done with randomizing circles, now my challenge is on adding circles to a straight line queue like the actual queue(i want the circles to queue from left to right preferably at the top of the Frame. When i call the removeCircle(), i want the circle to leave the queue and move down the frame. Can you help me with the addCircle() and removeCircle() methods. Thank you in advance.

Comment: i am looking for help on my assignment. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i managed to get this, But still having a challenge in creating a LinkedList to hold the circles in a queue. im pasting my code here

Comment: Why do you need a LinkedLIst. Just use an ArrayList. You can create 2 Swing Timers. When the "add" Timer fires you add a circle to the ArrayList. When the "remove" Timer fires you remove the circle from index 0 from the ArrayList. So you basic logic is correct. However, you don't need a loop in the ActionListner of the Timer. The Timer is the loop. It will generate an event every 10/15 seconds. Why are you use 40ms for the Timer if you want something to happen every 10/15 seconds?

Comment: @camickr thanks. I am now using an ArrayList. I managed to make progress. I created an application. I am having a challenge in Adding and removing. My program can now add 3 circles but they are not in a queue. I want them in a queue. And remove one circle after 5 seconds. And add one circle after 10 seconds. i do not know if there is a way for me to share my code.

Comment: The problem with two swing timers is the exception that i am getting : ConcurrentModificationException. How can i get rid of it??

Comment: `My program can now add 3 circles but they are not in a queue. I want them in a queue.` No idea what that means. The ArrayList is your queue. Every time the "add" Timer fires you generate a new random shape and add it to the ArrayList. `i am getting : ConcurrentModificationException.` You should NOT be iterating through the ArrayList and making modifications.

Comment: Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem. The ActionListener for the "add" Timer should be basically two lines of code: one to create the shape and the second to add it to the ArrayList. The "remove" ActionListener should be one line of code: remove the first item in the ArrayList.

Comment: the code is too big to add on comments section. Any other way to share??

Comment: The code should always be posted with the question. And the code should not be too big. Replace your original code with the updated code after incorporating all suggestions.

Comment: Just edited my code. Still having challenges on adding and removing circles from queue and generate random colors from 3 colors(Red, green, amber). Also i want my priority variable to be associated with the colors(for example in my code i used range 1 to 3 for priority, Let 1 denote amber, 2 denote green,, 3 denote red). Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solving should be done one problem at a time. Don't attempt to write the entire program before you start testing.

So break your program down to the basics:

1. You need a Timer for the animation to move each object. So start by adding a single object to the ArrayList and then when the Timer fires you iterate through the ArrayList and move each object. It doesn't matter that there is only a single object in the ArrayList to start.
2. Then you create another Timer that fires every 15 seconds to add another object to the ArrayList.
3. Then you add logic to give this object a random color
4. Then you add logic to give this object a priority.
5. Once all the above is done you add another Timer to remove and object from the ArrayList.

The basic structure of your code needs to be changed.

1. You should NOT be using static variables. So you need to redesign the structure of your classes.
2. You should have a CirclePanel class. This class will contain the properties needed to paint the objects, so it will contain the ArrayList. It will also need methods like "addCircle()" and "removeCircle()". These methods will be invoke by the appropriate Timer.
3. You need to use a Swing Timer for all the Timers, not a util Timer. When the Swing Timer fires the code will execute single threaded on the Event Dispatch Thread which should prevent the ConcurrentModificationException from happening.

Check out: [How do I paint multiple objetcs that move at different speeds in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358359/how-do-i-paint-multiple-objetcs-that-move-at-different-speeds-in-java/42358637#42358637) for an example to help with the restructuring.

It doesn't do everything you need but it is a good start. It will animate an ArrayList of object. So you will need to modify the code to populate the ArrayList one object at a time and remove one object at a time.

Edit:

If you want to add more circles then you need another Timer. Using the original code I provide you with you can do something like:

```
public void startAnimation()
{
    //Timer timer = new Timer(75, this);
    //timer.start();

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            move();
            repaint();
        }
    });
    timer.start();

    Timer timer2 = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            addBalls(1);
        }
    });
    timer2.start();
}
```

So the first Timer animates the balls already in the ArrayList. The second Timer adds a new ball to the ArrayList.

I'll let you write the Timer to remove a ball from the ArrayList. I have already suggested this is a single statement in the ActionListener.

Comment: I am asking for help to add circles in a queue. Like in a straight line queue, at a certain area on the Frame, preferably at the top of the queue.  . after that i will want to remove one circle from the queue after 15 seconds. when the removeCircle() method is called, i want one circle to move from the queue to the bottom of the circle. Can you kindly assist. I am having challenges  @camickr.

Comment: Edited my code. can you assist with addCircle() method and removeCircle() method. I want a circle to be added to the queue after each and every 10 seconds. Remove circle after each and every 15 seconds.

Comment: @TOUREDEEZ, what have you tried? I don't see any changes to the code other than you renamed the classes. Have you listened to any of my suggestions? Why do you still only have a single Timer? I have stated you need additional Timers for the "add" and "remove" logic? Where are your attempts to do this? Why did you move the "addBalls(...)" method into the constructor?? The whole point of keeping is separate is so you can add more balls at any time. See edit.

Comment: Thank you @camickr. But look i am having a challenge in structuring my who code as you suggested. Can you assist on that?? I have noted the issue of timers. And thank you once again.

Comment: BallAnimation4.java:35: error: BallPanel is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
    static class BallPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
           ^
BallAnimation4.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
            addBalls(1);
            ^
  symbol: method addBalls(int)
2 errors

Comment: Sorry, I have a slightly different version on my computer. I have updated the original link to contain my current version. You should be able to just replace the "startAnimation()" method from the link with the code provide above to demonstrate how to use multiple Timers.

Comment: I think i need personal assistance on my new challenges. Are you able to assist? Can i have your email address or anywhere I can get in touch with you??

Comment: I can be reached at the forum along will all the other users of the forum. When you have a problem you create your [mcve] and post the code along with a specific question and people will answer the question when they have time and know the answer.