# How to do a setLocation without repainting my JLabel

Tags: java, components, label, repaint, frames

I want to give the effect that the components move in time, however when I do a setLocation the label is repainted, this makes it repaint for each movement of each component, therefore for each movement the components are placed on top of each other and everything time is getting messy.
What I want to do is move the components without repainting my window, label, and later, after moving all the components, make a single repaint that always shows the correct frames. (Translated by google)

```
    public void run(){   //this method runs 60 times per second
        if(objects.size() > 0){
            for(int i=0; i<objects.size(); i++){
                objects.get(i).run(); //moves my JLabels with setLocation
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
```

Comment: We'll need an [mcve] at least to explain what is going on.  Better focus on one particular part of this issue would also help.

Comment: This is the way Swing works. When you change the location of a component the repaint() method is invoked and a request is made to the `RepaintManager`. The `RepaintManager` will then consolidate multiple repaint requests into a group repaint so all components are painted at the same time. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358359/how-do-i-paint-multiple-objetcs-that-move-at-different-speeds-in-java/42358637#42358637 for a complete working example.

Comment: Thank you very much, is there an alternative?